# Send wei to payable function with web3 async

Tags: web3js, metamask, meteor

I want to send 100wei to a payable function in my deployed contract. But i don't want to sign the transaction because of to much effort to get this going. I just want to submit the transaction with metamask. Therefore i need the correct web3 command to call my 'depositFunds' method and send 100 wei.
Currently i have this command, but i get frankly an error.
`myContractInstance.depositFunds().sendTransaction({from: web3.eth.accounts[0], gas: 3000000, value: 100}, function(err, res){});`

What do i have to change to get this going?

Comment: What is the full error message you get?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can call the method directly as follows without `sendTransaction`:

```
myContractInstance.depositFunds({from: web3.eth.accounts[0], gas: 3000000, value: 100}, function(err, res){});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a tutorial I wrote on interacting with smart contracts using MetaMask. Calling a payable function is the same as this, just add a value to the transaction:

https://medium.com/metamask/calling-a-smart-contract-with-a-button-d278b1e76705

You'll need the contract address and its ABI to call a method.