# Does view functions cost gas? And how to send transaction in a proper way?

Tags: contract-development, transactions, contract-invocation, view

I have a method defined as:
`getNames() view public` , if i call on it 
`contractInstance.getNames.estimatedGas()` it returns me a non-zero value, why? I mean, view methods should not consume any gas! On the other way, since this is a call it does not return to me a tx hash so i can't invoke the `eth.gettransactionReceipt`, how can i check if it really consumed gas ?

Furthermore, supposing `method()` is a set function of my deployed contract, hence  a transaction mining is needed, which is the difference between calling:

`contractInstance.method(args,{from:web3.eth.coinbase, gas:...})`

and calling:

`contractInstance.method.sendTransaction(args,{from:web3.eth.coinbase, gas:...})`

Answer (score 14):

> I mean, view methods should not consume any gas! On the other way, since this is a call it does not return to me a tx hash so i can't invoke the eth.gettransactionReceipt, how can i check if it really consumed gas ?

Pure and view functions actually do cost gas. But by calling them via RPC **only your local node** has to do the calculation and therefore the gas cost is simulated.

If a deployed contract calls these functions **everyone** in the network has to do the calculation and therefore they do have to cost gas.

> Furthermore, supposing method() is a set function of my deployed
>   contract, hence a transaction mining is needed, which is the
>   difference between calling:
>
> contractInstance.method(args,{from:web3.eth.coinbase, gas:...})
>
> and calling:
>
> contractInstance.method.sendTransaction(args,{from:web3.eth.coinbase,
>   gas:...})

The difference here is that by using `sendTransaction` you can send ether to the function. If the function is not `payable` it will fail.

Comment: Now is more clearer! One more thing, the .sendTransaction hence is used to call a function that can receive ether right? On the other way, if a function is not payabale it will just get the fucntion parameters with no ether. ?

Comment: Your first point is correct. If you want to use a method that isn't payable you don't have to use sendTransaction. A non-payable function will always revert if you try to send eth to it.

Comment: By the way: You actually don't have to use sendTransaction at all. You can specify the value you want to send as parameter as shown here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/27522/40051

Comment: Couldn't a deployed contract call a view or pure function without costing gas? Why does everyone need to perform the calculation if no change in state has been made?

Answer (score 13):

In solidity, if a function reads state but does not modify any state, this needs to be declared as **view** function.

If a function does not read any state and also does not modify any state, this can be declared as **pure** function.

If a  function modifies state in the blockchain, to invoke the method you need to make a transaction in the blockchain and **sendTransaction** is the api to do this.

**estimateGas** api provides the amount of gas to be incurred to access/modify in the blockchain.

In solidity, only making transaction will cost you gas. If you just directly call **view**/**pure** function, it will not cost you any gas.

Point to be noted that, if a view function is internally called inside a non **view** function, so this must be transaction as it is modifying state(**non view function**).

Any operation in the blockchain state will cost you gas in case of making transaction.

**sendTransaction** is only for sending ether, is not true. Sending ether/ updating any variable of a contract means changing in the state of blockchain. So this will be transaction and this will cost ether.

**estimateGas** is an api which gives  the estimation of gas to be incurred if that method is called as a part of a transaction.

**transactionReceipt** is returned only when a transaction has been added in the blockchain after being mined. So, in case of invoking **pure/view function**, you will not get either **transaction hash or receipt**.

Obviously, if a function needs to receive ether at the time of transaction, only then you will add **payable** modifier to the function.

Hope it will help you to understand the concept of transaction in ethereum blockchain.

For further information, go through the documentation of solidity.
[Solidity Documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.1/)